# Change the order of table rows on page load

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to figure out if its possible to automatically tweak the order of several table rows when the page is loaded.

I do not need any drag and drop functionality. It should be done automatically when the page is loaded.

I have about a dynamically generated table with about 10 rows and each row has its own class:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Reference">
      <th>Reference</th>
      <td>3302</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Manufacturer">
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <td>Cuttler-Hammer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Model">
      <th>Model</th>
      <td>V48M28E45B45 KVA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Year">
      <th>Year Manufactured</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Tonage">
      <th>Tonage</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Shot">
      <th>Shot Size Oz</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Size">
      <th>Shot Size Grams</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Spacing">
      <th>Tie Bar Spacing</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Platen">
      <th>Platen Size</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to re-order the table to that the 2nd row is 1st, the 3rd row is 2nd, and the 1st row is 3rd.

I've been sitting here trying to figure out how to do it with jQuery or Javascript for the past 45 minutes, but I am hitting a wall.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Use the `:nth-child(n)` selector in JQuery :)

Comment: How would this be structured? I wasn't even aware that I could use nth-child with jQuery

Comment: Do you need just the first three ordered or all of them?

Comment: Just the first 3 yes, all others will remain where they are.

Comment: Ok, well no ones going to do it for you! put what jQuery you have tried and we can have a go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

Add an id to the `<tbody>`. Otherwise use a CSS selector (not shown).

```
<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Write some javascript that runs at `window.document.ready()`

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(window.document).ready(function () {
    var tableRows = Array(), 
      i = 0, 
      tempRow = undefined;

    //clone each row node to the local array
    $('#table-body').children().each(function cloneRowsToArray() {
        tableRows.push($(this).clone());
    });

    //re-order the array as necessary
    tempRow = tableRows[0];
    tableRows[0] = tableRows[1];
    tableRows[1] = tempRow;

    //re-write the newly arranged rows.
    $('#table-body').children().each(function replaceEachRowFromArray() {
        $(this).replaceWith(tableRows[i]);
        i += 1;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but as far as I can see, its not working. Check in a jsFiddle and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Works fine for me.. The Manufacturer row is first and the Reference row is second.. If you look at my sample re-order logic, all I did was swap the order of those two rows.  Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8a2soqe3/

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. Had a jQuery conflict on my page. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a javascript function on body onload event that use jquery functions [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to move specific elements before or after other ones.
Its just an idea and not a concrete solution but i hope can help you.